# How do I know a MySQL user has the maximum privileges possible?

Tags: mysql, root

A little background: A while back I replaced my "root" user with "me" but forgot to give "me" access to the "mysql" table.  Tonight I ran "safe" mode with "--skip-grant-tables" and this helped me gain access again:

`UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='me';`

However, I'm wondering if this grants "me" the maximum privileges possible?  I just want to make sure "me" has full access.  I don't want to find out a year from now this user is lacking some awesome superpower I need during a crisis.

This in particular has me scratching my head:

```
mysql> grant all on *.* to me@localhost with grant option;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)
```

Are 0 rows affected because "me" already has all privileges or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just do:

```
USE mysql;

SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE user = 'me' AND host = 'localhost';
```

And if you see all the `Y` and none `N` you have full :D

Comment: Sounds good to me.  I'm using "pager less" but for whatever reason "less" isn't showing me the first three columns :-/  Now I just need to work on the Ns.

Comment: FWIW I was only missing this "update user set Create_tablespace_priv='Y' where user='me';"

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES`;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`USER_PRIVILEGES`;
```

Change root user for your user...

```
SELECT Host,    Select_priv,    Insert_priv,    Update_priv,    Delete_priv     FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = "root";
SELECT Host,    Create_priv,    Drop_priv,  Reload_priv,    Shutdown_priv   FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = "root";
SELECT Host,    Process_priv,   File_priv,  Grant_priv,     References_priv FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = "root";
SELECT Host,    Index_priv, Alter_priv, Show_db_priv,   Super_priv  FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = "root";
SELECT Host,    Create_tmp_table_priv,  Lock_tables_priv,   Execute_priv    FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = "root";
SELECT Host,    Repl_slave_priv,    Repl_client_priv,   Create_view_priv    FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = "root";
SELECT Host,    Show_view_priv,     Create_routine_priv,    Alter_routine_priv  FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = "root";
SELECT Host,    Create_user_priv,   Event_priv,         Trigger_priv,   Create_tablespace_priv  FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = "root";
SELECT Host,        ssl_type    , ssl_cipher    , x509_issuer,  x509_subject,   max_questions           FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = "root";
SELECT Host, max_updates, max_connections,      max_user_connections        FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = "root";
SELECT Host, plugin, authentication_string  FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = "root";
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also some good information here:

`show grants;`

https://serverfault.com/questions/386903/mysql-grant-option

For example "To be able to do a GRANT ALL on another or new user, the user issuing the GRANT ALL must themselves have every permission or the grant will fail."